# How to safely upgrade server OS version that running Hadoop Namenode?

Tags: hadoop, upgrade, failover

## env

hadoop 3.2.1 version

## question

I'm operating a Hadoop cluster with ha configuration.
I have to upgrade my os version of namenode server. Cent 6 to 7.
zkfc, journalnode, resourcemanager and namenode daemon are located on each ha server.
After shutting down all daemons from the standby server, I want to work in a way that upgrades the os.
My scenario

1. shut down hadoop daemons of standby server
2. os upgrade
3. recover standby server daemons
4. haadmin failover
5. repeat

Are there any anticipated problems?
I wonder if there is better way other than this one.

Comment: You'll need to edit all of the YUM repos and ensure there is an EL7 version available first

Comment: I use the binary installation version, should I check the yum repo as well?

Comment: There's still OS dependencies that Hadoop needs like sshd, java, etc that come from YUM. In any case, you should upgrade the datanodes before you upgrade any primary/standby services